# Adding an arbitrary symbol after the number in an enumerate environment

Tags: lists, enumerate

I want to create an enumerated list, but after the number I want to be able to add a symbol. Right now I can do it with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[1.$\diamondsuit$] First item
  \item[2.$\clubsuit$] Second item
  \item[3.$\spadesuit$] Third item
  \item[4.$\heartsuit$] Fourth item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document
```

which produces the following

[image]

However, in this example I added the numbers by hand. How could I add a symbol after the number, without needing to insert the number manually?

Inserting the symbol after the item, like `\item $\diamondsuit$` is not what I want, because the second line will be indented with respect to the number, and not to the bullet, which is "1.diamond".

**Clarification** I do not want exactly this scheme. I want to be able to chose the symbol to each item, for example: `\itemsymbol{$\diamondsuit$}` would add the diamond after the corresponding number.  (It may be the case for example that 1 and 2 are diamonds, 3 is a spade, etc, or whatever other symbol!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `enumitem` and `\itemsymbol`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{symenum}
 {\enumerate[label=\arabic*.\noexpand\thisenumsymbol,align=left]}
 {\endenumerate}
\newcommand\thisenumsymbol{}
\newcommand\itemsymbol[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\thisenumsymbol}{#1}%
  \item
}

\begin{document}
\begin{symenum}
  \itemsymbol{$\diamondsuit$}\label{first} First item
  \itemsymbol{$\clubsuit$} Second item
  \itemsymbol{$\spadesuit$} Third item
  \itemsymbol{$\heartsuit$} Fourth item
  \itemsymbol{} Fourth item
\end{symenum}

Here's the reference: \ref{first}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is much better than the other solution. It allows me to move the items without having to check whether I put it in a section with a symbol or another. The symbol is right in the item. Thanks!

Comment: I would add `\newcommand\refsymbol[1]{\renewcommand{\thisenumsymbol}{}\ref{#1}}` to be able to reference an item without carrying the symbol ;-)

Comment: @AlejandroDC Fixed, you can use `\ref`. If you *don't* want to carry the symbol, add `,ref=\arabic*.` to the optional argument to `enumerate` in the definition.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\zz#1{%
\ifcase#1\relax\or$\diamondsuit$\or$\clubsuit$\or$\spadesuit$\or$\heartsuit$\else?\fi}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.\zz{\value{enumi}}}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
  \item Fourth item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: David, when I see code like this I realize I still know very little. Is there some documentation that would help me understand this code?

Comment: @Alenanno The `\ifcase` in `\zz` is just the same as you see `\alph` or `\ftnsymbol` or any of the latex counter types other than arabic or roman, \label... is the macro use to print labels in enumerate. Probably one of the more readable documentation of those parameters is the enumitem package (which also gives an easier syntax for setting them as the other answer shows)

Comment: This solution is static. What I want is to chose what symbol to add to what item (the main idea is that I want to mark the items with different symbols, it may be the case that 1 and 2 are diamonds, 3 is a spade, etc.).

Comment: @AlejandroDC I'd never have guessed that from the question:-)

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Anyway, your solution helped to the final solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `enumitem.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\def\ctext#1{\expandafter\@ctext\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@ctext#1{\ifcase#1\or $\diamondsuit$\or 
  $\clubsuit$\or $\spadesuit$\or$\heartsuit$\or ?\fi}
\makeatother
\AddEnumerateCounter{\ctext}{\@ctext}{MyWidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.\ctext{enumi}]
\item foo
\item bar
\item baz
\item foobar
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT 1: After clarification of OP

A dynamic approach based on David's solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\def\switchenum#1{%
  \renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
  \switchenum{$\heartsuit$}
  \item First item  \switchenum{$\diamondsuit$}
  \item Second item 
  \item Third item  \switchenum{$\clubsuit$}
  \item Fourth item \switchenum{}
  \item Fifth item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is static. What I want is to chose what symbol to add to what item when I create the enumeration (the main idea is that I want to mark the items with different symbols, it may be the case that 1 and 2 are diamonds, 3 is a spade, etc.).

Comment: After the edit: Just amazing. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!